# PHP re-submission and subscription data issue

Tags: php, html-email, sendmail, form-submit, subscription

I'm facing two issue with the following code.

1. I'm using the following code to submit the subscriber's email address to my email address the code is working and email is also being sent but the issue is that I can't see subscriber's email address.
2. Every time when I refresh the page it shows an alert box saying resubmission confirmation and when I properly refresh the page by closing the alert box or pressing ok then it shows the success message that was showing while the subscriber submit his/her email.

The code is below :

```
     <?php

                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                  $email=$_POST['email'];

                  //send mail 
                 $to='info@soapbox.media';
                 $subject='New Subscriber';
                 $body='<html>
                 <body>
                 <h3>Feedback</h3>
                 <hr>

                 <p> Email :<br/>'.$email.'</p>

                 </body>

                 </html>';

                 $headers  ="From:<".$email.">\r\n";
                 $headers .="reply-To:".$email."\r\n";
                 $headers .="NINE-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                 $headers .="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";

              //confirmation mail
                         $user=$email;
                         $usersubject = "SoapBox";
                         $userheaders = "From:  info@soapbox.media\n";
                         $usermessage = "Thank you for subscribing SoapBox.";


                        //sending process
                         $send=mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
                         $confirm=mail($user, $usersubject, $userheaders,$usermessage );

                         if($send && $confirm){
                          echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show'>
                            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                            <strong>Success!</strong> You have subscribed successfully.
                          </div>";    
                         }

                         else{
                          echo "Failed";
                         }

                        }




?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['email']);` what's the value?

Comment: Oh; this is a typo question. You mixed up the headers' arguments in the 2nd `mail()` function.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry but didn't get you . what do you want to say ?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner please provide me the solution.

Comment: `$confirm=mail($user, $usersubject, $usermessage, $userheaders);`

Comment: but it's not the solution . I tried it and I want the refreshing issue that I've mentioned to be solved too.

Comment: Is there anyone available to answer this question please?

Answer (score 0):

1. `$confirm=mail($user, $usersubject, $usermessage, $userheaders);` by @Funk Forty Niner
2. place a `header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` after you've sent the mail - you will get rid of the post-header, so no more popup after F5 - You will get rid of your confirmation msg aswell so you could add a `GET` parameter to your URL to show the confirmation message.

Comment: I tried the first answer it's not working and if I implement the second one then how will I show the success message ?

Comment: Kindly If you can help me ASAP

Comment: `header('location: example.php?success');` in your script `if(isset($_GET['success''])) { echo '...'; }`

Comment: I'm not getting you as I'm not using any external file like you are specifying example.php . kindly make changes to code I provided above please so that I can implement that

Comment: @HaseebMustafa `example.php` is the file you are writing this code in. replace it by the uri you use to get to this file - look into your browser adress-bar ;)

Comment: i gave you the tools and some hints - now start coding :)